# Text Not Appearing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, text, cs5

I'm designing a logo and I'm almost finished but I'm trying to add text to the logo to finish it off but the text won't appear. No matter what color I make the text it just doesn't appear. Anyone know why this could be? I'm using Photoshop CS5.1 extended by the way.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD. Can you please provide us with screenshots and tell us what you have tried? It would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts. Are you sure you have chosen the text-tool, and with a font-size that is actually big enough to see?

Maybe:

*You are using the text-tool on a layer where text is "not allowed".*

or

*the layer you are putting text in, is behind something else. Go an look in your layers-panel and see if the sorting of layers are wrong.*

Comment: I am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I had such frustrating time trying to solve it only to find that the presets when I create a new file were all wrong. The resolution was some 9.2 pixels. I've no idea how the presets got messed up. But I set it back to 72 pixels, and it's now alright. Hope that helps. :)